# iTunes 12.5.5.5 can no longer delete subscribed podcasts

Tags: ios, itunes, software-update, podcasts

I have used iTunes for years, and now suddenly after an update I can no longer delete a subscribed podcast.  I am used to simply right-clicking and selecting "Delete From Library on the picture of the podcast as in this picture:

[image: selecting "delete from library"]

But this no longer deletes the podcast subscription from my library.  It gives me a prompt to delete local files, which I select "yes, of course" to... and after it deletes the local mp3's... it does a big fat nothing, and the stupid smug podcast I want to get rid of just sits there staring me in the face, mocking me with it's existence.  I am able to unsubscribe, but still... the stupid, smug icon just sits there... mocking me.  Against all reasonable logic, optimistically waits for me to change my mind like an orphaned puppy that just will not get the hint.  I am not your new dad "reply all" podcast.  Go away.  You're messing up my house.  I'm allergic.  Please stop batting those cute eyes at me, we're not good for each other.  You know it.  I know it.  Now scram!  Get outta here.

Please, if possible, explain to me how I am the stupid party in this partnership, and not Apple.  All I did was update iTunes.  I cringe every time I do it, because of stuff like this.  Before the update, this worked just fine.

Comment: 6/3/19 Ditto here after years of being able to delete. Leave it to Apple to leave us out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just click the podcast and press, "delete" (backspace)

I experienced the same issue, removing the podcast from the menu did nothing.

Comment: Works for me. It's pretty amazing, though, this is what it comes to in software from a company known for its ostensible UX prowess. Something's wrong in Cupertino.

Answer (score 0):

I partially share your problem. I'm running 12.6.1,25 and I go to the podcast menu and try to delete individual episodes and it does nothing. Cannot delete anything.
If I go up a level and delete the whole podcast it works. Then I have to go find the podcast and re-establish it.
Another strange thing- All podcasts have been queued up going back to the first episode of each one. There should only be the latest unread ones there.